# Error when integrate SheetJS on Angular 4 + SystemJS (angular-seed)

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular-seed, sheetjs

I'm using this seed project with Angular 4 and SystemJS ([angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed))

And want to use SheetJS to export Excel file. I follow the instruction, can import xlsx fine, but when export file it constantly return error:

```
XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet is not a function
```

I have added to the project.config.ts

```
 ...
 {
    name: 'xlsx',
    // Path to the package's bundle
    path: 'node_modules/xlsx/dist',
    packageMeta: {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      main: 'xlsx.core.min.js'
    }
  }
```

And even modify the seed.config.ts

```
meta: {
    'xlsx': {
        exports: 'XLSX' // <-- this is needed to tell SystemJS to expose XLSX
    }
},
map: {
    'fs': '',     // <--|
    'crypto': '', // <--| suppress native node modules
    'stream': '', // <--|
},
```

But still cannot make the SystemJS understand to import XLSX correctly.

Anyone has faced this problem before can suggest me how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue (but in a react app) the “xlsx.core.min.js” won’t really work

I never used angular but I imagine a config like this could work

```
{
    name: 'xlsx',
    // Path to the package's bundle
    path: 'node_modules/xlsx',
    packageMeta: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'xlsx.js'
    }
}
```

Also i would suggest to use “code splitting”, if available to your project, because this is a huge dependency